Long Execution Time and Py4JNetworkError When Using Cube Function with Many Dimensions in Spark
I'm facing performance issues and network errors when using the cube function in Spark with a larger number of dimensions. Below, I've detailed the problem, including the error messages and the troubleshooting steps I've taken so far.
Problem Description:
I am using the cube function in Spark as shown in the following code snippet:
authorization_df.cube(dimension_list).agg(sum("approved_repeat_txn_amt").alias("approved_repeat_txn_amt"))

The function executes without issues when I use 14 dimensions but starts to fail with the following error when I increase the number of dimensions to 24:
Error Message:
raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty
INFO:py4j.clientserver:Closing down clientserver connection

Troubleshooting Steps Attempted:
Spark Configuration Adjustments: Updated the Spark configuration to address potential library path issues:
--conf spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sys_apps_01/python/python310/openssl/lib/
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sys_apps_01/python/python310/openssl/lib/

Memory Increase: Increased memory allocation for both executor and driver to handle larger data volumes:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("YourAppName") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "10g") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "10g") \
    .getOrCreate()

Network Timeout Settings: Adjusted the network timeout settings:
spark.conf.set("spark.network.timeout", 800)
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", 60)

Alternative Aggregation Approach: Tried preaggregating the data and using window functions as an alternative method:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

window_spec = Window.partitionBy(["dim1", "dim2", "dim3"])
result_df = authorization_df.withColumn("approved_repeat_txn_amt", F.sum("approved_repeat_txn_amt").over(window_spec))  

Despite these efforts, the problem persists with 24 dimensions but not with 14. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest further troubleshooting steps or configurations that might help?
Thank you for your assistance!
